# Can write but cannot read Unicode from MYSQL table using java and jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unicode

I can successfully write to a mysql database table using java/jdbc for the unicode text "привет моя работа программист"

When I search the database table using the mysql command prompt on windows 10 I see the exact text in the table.

However when I read the text back using java jbdc the text from the result set is as follows

Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ Ð¼Ð¾Ñ Ñ€Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ‚Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ð¸ÑÑ‚

The url I use to call is

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`

I use the following code

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_STATEMENT_EMAIL);

        ps.setString(1, idemail);
        ps.setString(2, password);


        ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();

         if (res.next()) {
String description = res.getString("description");
    }
```

I have converted the database and database table to utf8 using the following commands

`ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That gibberish is your text, encoded to bytes using *utf-8*, and then decoded using *windows-1252*. But I'm not sure which step exactly is using the wrong encoding. My guess is you're opening the database connection using the *default encoding*.

Comment: I think I found a solution. Instead of calling ResultSet.getString() I called ResultSet.getbytes() then created a new string from the bytes. This strangely seemed to work.

Comment: That may work but it sounds like a workaround. Can you post the line of code used to establish the connection to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Change the file encoding to UTF8.
Most likely, you have IntelliJ IDEA that likes to change the encoding of the file...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fear you have two problems.

`Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ Ð¼` sounds like Mojibake.

In trying to decode that, I get `привет мо� работа программи�т`.  The black diamonds usually come from the wrong `<meta...>` on the output page.  But they must be coming from somewhere else.

Never mind.  I see that `я` is `D18F`.  But `8F`, treated as latin1 seems to be a non-printing character, thereby messing up the cadence of 2-byte utf8 codes, leading to the black diamond.

The decoding was `BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1))`, but I suspect that cannot be relied upon.

Mojibake usually comes from

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- xx The column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (Or possibly it was inherited from the table/database.)  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

So, that gives you two things to fix.  And, sorry, but I don't think the data already in the table can be fixed.  However, I could look deeper, if you provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` showing either that string, or at least some string with `я` or `с` in it.